# In AppCompat library showasaction dosent work

Tags: android, android-appcompat

ActionBar show only icon. How to get icon and text?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="@string/add"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        >
    </item>
</menu>
```

My xml menu file.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My code.

Answer (score 0):

always|withText' will work if there is sufficient room, otherwise it will only place icon. You can test it on your phone with rotation.

if you want to show always text with icon follow the below step for work around

In Style.xml make sure parent is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

Now Include Toolbar like in which layout you want to add menu action.

toolbar_with_add.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Make sure you include support library like fro toolbar like below in your build.gradle file.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

You can also change the drawable prosition by changing the "android:drawableRight" to "android:drawableLeft", "android:drawableBottom" ,"android:drawableTop"